# Use Google OAuth 2.0 refresh token without client_secret

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

So I know it is bad to store the client_secret in a client side app (in my case a mobile app); however, the below link is the only link which describes how to use your refresh token for Google OAuth 2.0 and it requires the client_secret.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#refresh-tokens

My question:  Is it possible to use Google OAuth 2.0 in a client side app without using/storing the client_secret?  I know that Windows Live Connect's flavor of OAuth 2.0 allows you to refresh your token without specifying the client_secret, but I have not yet discovered a way to do this with Google's API.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate workflow for using OAuth2 on installed applications or devices.

See link below to relevant google documentation

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Devices](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices)